# How to create/push/pull a hg bare remote repo at bitbucket.org

Tags: windows, mercurial, dvcs, tortoisehg

I have a local project with `hg init`. I created an empty remote repo at bitbucket.org. The url is for example https://bitbucket.org/myusername/helloworld. I want it as a bare remote repo without working directory.

According to the instruction at Bitbucket while creating a new rep, I could upload my local repo to the remote repo using `hg push`, but it is containing the working directory.

```
cd \path\to\myproject
hg push https://myusername@bitbucket.org/myusername/helloworld
```

How can I create a bare remote repo which is a clone of my local project (repo)?
And can I do sync/push/pull with the bare remote repo without working directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's some confusion here.  All repos at bitbucket are "bare" (not really a mercurial term).  You can't see the working directory at bitbucket (it's on their servers), so if you're concluding that your repo at bitbucket is "bare" you're looking at the wrong thing or misunderstanding what the term means.

Your local repo could be called "bare" if the local working directory has no files.  You can see what that looks like by doing `hg update null`.   You can get files back in your working directory by doing `hg update`.  But bare/non-bear only makes sense when you're talking about a clone to which you have disk access.  When you follow those bitbucket steps above you're creating an "empty" repository at BB w/ no changesets in it, and then the `hg push` moves those changesets (aka commits) over there.  Afterward, it's no longer empty, but it's still "bare".

Comment: I'm new to mercurial/git. So, I'm quite confusing about the terms and logic. I could use the term "bare" for my local repo if it has only folder ".hg". If all repos at bitbucket are "bare", they're presenting the working directory from `.hg/store/data`? Then, push/pull are only interacting with `.hg/store/data`? Not uploading/downloading the actual working files?

Comment: You are correct in all of those statements. Bitbucket has very tight repository-level integration & they serve the files and build their web displays entirely from what's in the `.hg/...` space. On any repo `push` and `pull` affect only the `.hg/...` space and not the working directory. You'll find even the `hgweb` that ships with Mercurial is the same way. Try this: `hg update null ; hg share`. Locally you'll have no files in your working directory, but visit the URL with a web browser there they are. Bottom line: bare vs not bare is an implementation detail if the repo isn't on your machine.